# Why is Frame Selected not working?

Tags: navigation

I am working on a Blender Guru project which includes 6 separate meshes. I am frustrated because the *Frame Selected* (hotkey Numpad .) stopped working.
[image]
The mesh object that I want framed is selected and my *3D Viewport* is in *Layout* mode.
When I click *View* and then *Frame Selected* then my view does not center on the selected object (it might zoom closer).
I don't have this problem if I work on another or new projects. How do I get *Frame Selected* to work again?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue. In my case I had a View Lock (under View menu) to another object. Once I removed the lock I could use the view frame select or the numpad . key.

Comment: I love you! You saved my evening! <3

Answer (score 2):

in my case, in view lock menu.. i was locked on 3d cursor lul what a messs